# How to remove Rust compiler toolchains with Rustup?

Tags: rust, rustup

The Rustup documentation shows how to [install Rust nightly](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs#working-with-nightly-rust), but not how to remove it.

While the docs do show how to uninstall `rustup` entirely, I'd like to keep the stable branch.

How can I uninstall Rust nightly?

---

Note that I attempted to do the opposite of `rustup install nightly`...

- `rustup uninstall nightly`
- `rustup remove nightly`
- `rustup delete nightly`

... to no avail.

Even though I read the documentation it wasn't clear that `nightly` was a `toolchain`, a `channel`... or something else.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The command you're looking for is:

```
rustup toolchain remove nightly
```

`remove` and `uninstall` both work for this.

For more details see:

```
rustup help toolchain
```

Comment: Thanks, was thrown by `install` inferring *toolchain* where `uninstall` doesn't. - reported https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/957

Comment: This does not seem to remove specific toolchains already installed under `~/.rustup/toolchains/` ... Did `for i in nightly-*; do rustup toolchain remove ${i/%-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu}; done`. The toolchains were taking a huge amount of space (~36 GB).

Answer (score 14):

You might have more than one nightly toolchain installed. To list all installed toolchains, run `rustup show`. The output will look like this:

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/fpoli/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-2018-06-27-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2021-02-24-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2021-09-20-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.54.0 (a178d0322 2021-07-26)
```

Now that you know the installed versions, you can remove them with the following command:

```sh
rustup toolchain remove nightly-2018-06-27 nightly-2021-02-24 nightly-2021-09-20
```