# What exactly is a Rust "toolchain"?

Tags: rust, toolchain, rustup

I've seen `rustup` be referred to as a "toolchain installer", but it's hard to find an exact definition of what Rust considers a "toolchain" to be and what the scope is for the concept.

I already have the Rust compiler and Cargo installed. What more does `rustup` bring? Is it just a Rust-version-switcher?

---

As a .NET-developer, maybe there is there a parallel which makes it easier for me to grasp this concept?

Comment: A terse definition is given in the [rustup README.md on Github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup#toolchain-specification): _"Many rustup commands deal with toolchains, a single installation of the Rust compiler. rustup supports multiple types of toolchains. The most basic track the official release channels: stable, beta and nightly; but rustup can also install toolchains from the official archives, for alternate host platforms, and from local builds."_I don't know if an exact definition exists, behind the generic notion of a [software toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain)

Comment: You can run `rustup toolchain list` which in my case prints `stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)`. So you can think of the toolchain as a specific version of the compiler, the standard library and the accompanying tools such as clippy, cargo, etc

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A toolchain is a specific version of the collection of programs needed to compile a Rust application. It includes, but is not limited to:

- The compiler, `rustc`
- The dependency manager and build tool, `cargo`
- The documentation generator, `rustdoc`
- The static and/or dynamic libraries comprising the standard library for the default platform

There are additional *components* that can be installed, such as

- Documentation

  - The Rust Programming Language
  - The standard library
  - Various books and references
- The static and/or dynamic libraries comprising the standard library for additional platforms to cross-compile to
- The source code for the standard library
- Extra utilities

  - Code formatting via `rustfmt`
  - Extra lints via `clippy`
  - Undefined behavior checking via `miri`
  - Advanced editor support via `rust-analyzer` or the Rust Language Server

Rustup provides ways to install, remove, update, select and otherwise manage these toolchains and their associated pieces.

See also:

- [How to install a Rust target for a specific rustup toolchain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53210121/155423)
- [How to remove Rust compiler toolchains with Rustup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42322879/155423)
- [How to switch between rust toolchains](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58226545/155423)
- [How do I tell which Windows toolchain my Rust compiler is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50687861/155423)
- [How to execute cargo test using the nightly channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48593858/155423)

Comment: The linker is also part of the toolchain. It's significant enough to include in the list.

Comment: @IInspectable can you point me to which platforms rustup installs a linker for? My understanding is that Rust relies on the system linker (which is why you also have to install a C toolchain).

Comment: That's my understanding too, but @linspectable's point is well taken, even if it's only to explain that this is one part that rustup doesn't handle. Especially since it can get messy when you're cross compiling.